# Making client side authorization to Facebook using Javascript JQuery

Tags: facebook, authorization

Here is what I want to:
I used OAuth 2.0 authorization system.
I already registered my application in Facebook, and I have got my application secret keys (i did server side code, but I need more user friendy authorization system).

Based on response from Facebook, how can I get response code from Facebook without reloading the page? In case you didn't understand what I mean take a look on next example:

Example is on this link:
http://www.badminton.si/1-turnir-b-kategorije-1-kolo-mbl

How can I then continue to get my access token so I can access my private information (like email)?

IN SHORT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js"> </script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
FB.init({
  appId: my_api_key,
  status: true,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {login();)}
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {logout();});
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {if (response.session) {login();}});
function login() {FB.api('/me', function (response) {alert(response.email)});
....

<fb:login-button v="2" size="large" autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,read_stream">
</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the examples on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

On most of the functions you'll get callbacks that you can catch to get a token without having to reload the page.

From the documentation:

```
FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
    } else {
      // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
    }
  });
```

With the `response.session` object you should get everything you need without having to reload the page.

Comment: Please provide me with a concrete example how to get redirected url (answer from Facebook) withou reloading the page. Don't redirect me on Facebook documentation. I read it (I realised it on server side already)!

Comment: @gregor: The callback URL is the one you set. I edited my answer with how to check if the user clicked on a login button or any other login solution

Comment: you need also:
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js"> </script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
AND DONT FORGET
fb:login-button v="2" size="large" autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,read_stream"></fb:login-button>